# Comparing negatives (It is nice not to be rude.) vs. (It isn't nice to be rude.)

Tags: grammar, differences, syntactic-analysis

What is the difference in style and meaning between the following two in terms of the adjective "nice"?

- (It is nice **not** to be rude.)
- (It is**n't** nice to be rude.)

besides, what is the difference in style and meaning between the following two in terms of the verb "decide"?

- (I decided **not** to come)
- (I did**n't** decide to come.)

Answer (score 2):

Both sentences are formally correct in their meanings.

Compare:

It is nice not to be rude.= It is ***nice*** to be polite.

It isn't nice to be rude.= It is ***bad*** to be rude.

Though, from the stylistic point of view, the first sentence sounds strange because '***nice***' is a 'positive' adjective and needs a  'positive' word (for example,  polite).

Answer (score 1):

"I decided not to come" = I made up my mind that I would not.

"I didn't decide to come" could be followed by something like "...until I heard that you would be coming too" or "...my friends just bundled me into the car."

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to apply the negative to the word it is affecting in the sentence.

These are closer in meaning but each relates to either side of neutrality.

> It's nice not to be rude

Is a bit more positive/complimentary - you are saying that by simply not being rude you are being nice.

> It isn't nice to be rude

In this case you're not making any comment about *not* being rude (e.g. - you might have to do a bit more work than just not be rude if you want to be nice). But certainly if you *are* rude, you are not being nice.

It's a bit more clear with your second group.

> I decided not to come.

Here you made a decision - that you were not going to come.

> I didn't decide to come.

Whereas here you did not necessarily make a decision.